Handling missing values in GAMs
I am currently fitting a GAM-model, which assumes that the price of a house P can be modelled as a sum of smooth effects from different distances $d_{1}, d_{2}, ...$, e.g. distance to coast, lake, railway etc etc.
\begin{align}
P = \sum_{i} s(d_{i})
\end{align}
Now, the key issue is that my distances are only given up to a certain cap value $d_{i,0}$, which I do not decide. As an example I have data of coastal distances up to 1500m. This means that roughly 10% of my data points have a coastal distance between 0m and 1500m, while the remaining are censored by the truncation. As I do not want to throw away all of this data (for a large number of distance-variable is it very likely that at least one will be censored), I have so far used the approach of simply imputing the censored distances to the cap value. In the example of the coastal distance I would impute all the censored distances to 1500m. I expect this imputation approach should work well if the cap-values are large enough that each distance-effect has vanished at its respective cap-value, but I am not sure if this is the case*. Does anyone have a better way of approaching the many missing values? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/mgcv/html/missing.data.html provides some guidance on how to handle missing values, but the example was quite hard to follow and I am unsure whether this is even the right way to go.
*To clarify the above point I considered a toy example of fitting a spline to a set of (x, y)-values from an exponential function where I subsequently cap the x-values at different points. The plots and the code are shown below. Evidently imputation works well when the cap is large compared to the decay length of the exponential but not so nicely otherwise.
cap <- 3
x <- seq(1, 10, length.out = 100)
x_capped <- pmin(x, cap)
y <- exp(-x)

data <- as.data.frame(list(x = x, x_capped = x_capped, y = y))


s1 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x),
            data = data,
            family = gaussian())

s2 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x_capped),
            data = data,
            family = gaussian())


data$x_capped = x

y_s1 <- predict.gam(s1, data, response = TRUE)
y_s2 <- predict.gam(s2, data, response = TRUE)


plot(x,y)
lines(x, y_s1, col = "red", lty = "dashed", lwd = 2)
lines(x, y_s2, col = "blue", lty = "dashed", lwd = 2)
abline(v = cap, col = "black", lty = "dashed")




(1) These aren't NAs: they are censored data.  Search our site for effective methods commonly applied in such circumstances.  (2) Setting all of them to the threshold is biased.  It's about the worst possible procedure because of that.  (3) You don't have an imputation problem: it looks rather like an extrapolation, which unfortunately isn't based on any information, but solely on your expectation for the form the extrapolation ought to take (which is a risky assumption in most fields).

Your post is quite confusing; reading it, it implies the $x$ covariate values but that doesn't seem to be the case as you are setting $y_i = x_0$ where $x_0$ is the cap value (whatever that means). If $x_0$ relates to $y$, that's just unnecessarily confusing.  From your second figure, y is larger than the cap value for several observations before the dotted line. I don't follow that; shouldn't it known up to the dotted line and then drop to the cap value? If the true $y$ is not observed but is less than this cap value, then your response is left censored. If you don't observe $y$...

when a covariate falls below/above some value then you have a truncated response. Either setting requires you to do something. What you should do remains unclear (to me at least) because you post if very confusing. You refer to your distance variables as $x_1$ etc and the cap value as being related to distance: "my distances are only given up to a certain cap value" while you refer to your response as a "measured variable". Please clarify. I suspect whuber's interpretation is correct, in which case please don't use the LoD as $y$. If you clarify I can make two suggestions; with mgcv and brms

Hi Gavin, I am not sure what you mean by me setting $y_{i} = x_{0}$ but I agree that my post was not well explained. I have tried to make it clearer. I hope it is a bit more understandable now. I would greatly appreciate your suggestions.
